# View properties of a class

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a typescript class defined as:

```
export class MyModel {
  ID: number;
  TYPE_ID: number;
  RECOMMENDED_HOURS: number;
  UNASSIGNED_HOURS: number;
}
```

In another .ts file I create an instance of it in a component:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   newModel: MyModel;
   ngOnInit() {
     this.newModel= new MyModel();
     this.newModel.RECOMMENDED_HOURS = 35;
     this.newModel.UNASSIGNED_HOURS = 28;
     debugger;
   }
```

When I inspect this.newModel after the hours are set, I don't see the `ID` or `TYPE_ID` properties, chrome debugger shows only the HOURS properties which are set.  Is there anyway to see them all regardless of them being set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to manually instanciate them to undefined.

This can be explained by [looking at the compiled code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Y%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop1%3A%20string%20%3D%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%7D) : instanciating a variable in TS makes it instanciated in JS, no matter the value. Since the value for unset variables is `undefined`, simply instanciate them to undefined.

```
class X {
    prop1: string;
}

class Y {
    prop1: string = undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use constructor inside your ts class:

```
export class MyModel {
    ID: number;
    TYPE_ID: number;
    RECOMMENDED_HOURS: number;
    UNASSIGNED_HOURS: number;

    constructor() {
        this.ID      = 0; // or whatever you want, null, undefined...
        this.TYPE_ID = 0; // same as above...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why not simply put it at declaration level ?

Comment: @trichetriche you can do that also, yes